# Extract string content from a seemingly binary .dic file

Tags: binary, hex

I'm working on an offline dictionary, which contains .dic files that I'd like to parse. when I open them with a text editor or with an hex editor, [I don't get anything readable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzBR4.png). 
I'm quite new to computer sciences and still a bit confused about this ANSI, UTF etc... encoding thingy. I've searched the web intensively but couldn't find any solution. Does anybody knows how to do to get readable text? 
Thanks

Comment: which format are `.dic` files in?

Comment: That's the problem, I don't even know how to find this information...

Comment: Do you know which program created the file?  I looked [online](http://file.org/extension/dic) and there many files that use this extension.

Comment: That's [an old English-French dictionary](http://grand-dictionnaire-hachette-oxford.software.informer.com/1.1/) that's been discontinued. Thanks for the link, I'll try this software and see if it works.